# count array element with specific condition

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array.
Now its a json array:

```
{
  "status":"OK",
  "details":{
    "Jun":[
      {
        "id":"8",
        "order_id":"0",
        "client_id":"0",
        "driver_id":"3",
        "status":"accept",
        "order_date":"2017-06-22"
      },
      {
        "id":"13",
        "order_id":"1",
        "client_id":"0",
        "driver_id":"3",
        "status":"accept",
        "order_date":"2017-06-22"
      },
      {
        "id":"33",
        "order_id":"1",
        "client_id":"0",
        "driver_id":"3",
        "status":"decline",
        "order_date":"2017-06-22"
      }
    ],
    "Apr":[
      {
        "id":"7",
        "order_id":"12",
        "client_id":"15",
        "driver_id":"3",
        "status":"accept",
        "order_date":"2014-04-10"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My data show as monthly now.

I want to show array monthly but calculate `total accepted`, `total request`, `total decline`.

My expected Output look like:

```
{
  "status":"OK",
  "details":{
    "Jun":[
      {
        "total accepted":"2",
        "total decline":"1",
        "total request":"3"
      }
    ],
    "Apr":[
      {
        "total accepted":"1",
        "total decline":"0",
        "total request":"1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My Current PHP CODE is:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $details_sort[] = $row;
}

$monthlyDetails = array();

foreach ($details_sort as $detail)
{
  $monthName = date('M', strtotime($detail['order_date']));

  if (! array_key_exists($monthName, $monthlyDetails) )
  {  
    $monthlyDetails[$monthName] = array();
  }

  array_push($monthlyDetails[$monthName], $detail);             
}
```

I can not understand how to calculate `total accepted`, `total request`, `total decline`. Please give me some example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) like;

```
<?php

$json = '{
    "status":"OK",
    "details":{
        "Jun":[
            {
                "id":"8",
                "order_id":"0",
                "client_id":"0",
                "driver_id":"3",
                "status":"accept",
                "order_date":"2017-06-22"
            },
            {
                "id":"13",
                "order_id":"1",
                "client_id":"0",
                "driver_id":"3",
                "status":"accept",
                "order_date":"2017-06-22"
            }
,
            {
                "id":"33",
                "order_id":"1",
                "client_id":"0",
                "driver_id":"3",
                "status":"decline",
                "order_date":"2017-06-22"
            }
        ],
        "Apr":[
            {
                "id":"7",
                "order_id":"12",
                "client_id":"15",
                "driver_id":"3",
                "status":"accept",
                "order_date":"2014-04-10"
            }
        ]
    }
}';

$array = json_decode(json, true);

$result = array();
foreach ($array["details"] as $key => $value) {
    $accepted = array_filter($value, function($item) {
        return $item["status"] === "accept";
    });

    $declined = array_filter($value, function($item) {
        return $item["status"] === "decline";
    }); 

    $result[$key] = array(
        "total_accepted" => count($accepted),
        "total_declined" => count($declined),
        "total_request"  => count($value)
    );
}

var_dump($result);
```

You can see demo here: **[Demo](http://ideone.com/83tzqR)**